# Why is my SVG element not appearing? (even when Inspecting my webpage)

Tags: html, css, svg, tailwind-css

So I tried to include an SVG element to my drop-menu, and I included the SVG attribute. However, it doesn't seem to be considered by any browser; even when inspecting the page, I cannot find the SVG attribute anywhere. Below is a sample of the code (notice I'm using CSS's utility framework Tailwind).

```html
<select class="font-semi bold text-sm appearance-none bg-gray-200 
        inline-block p-5 px-5 py-2 rounded-2xl ">
  <option value="Categor" disabled selected>Category</option>
  <option value="personal">Personal</option>
  <option value="buisness">Buisness</option>
  <option value="You">You</option>
  <svg class="transform -rotate-90 absolute pointer-events-none inline flex" style="right: 12px;" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22">
            <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <path stroke="#000" stroke-opacity=".012" stroke-width=".5"
                      d="M21 1v20.16H.84V1z">
                </path>
                <path fill="#222"
                      d="M13.854 7.224l-3.847 3.856 3.847 3.856-1.184 
                      1.184-5.04-5.04 5.04-5.04z">
                </path>
            </g>
        </svg>
</select>
```

I tried changing the place of the SVG element by placing it outside of the select element but still into the span element. This time, the SVG element was visible. However -and naturally- it was outside of the select element, rather on the extreme right (Even tho after inspecting the span element, it clearly contains the "category" space. I thought It could be a browser problem, so I tried on other ones (I'm using Chrome) and on the [Tailwind playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/), and nothing changes. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are putting svg inside a select tag.

A select tag only accepts two children:

- option
- optgroup

All other elements are **ignored**.

```html
<!--this works-->
<select>
  <optgroup label="opt group" />
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Here the two elements render inside.

Let's take a look at your code:

```html
            <span>
                <select class="font-semi bold text-sm appearance-none bg-gray-200 inline-block p-5 px-5 py-2 rounded-2xl ">
                    <option value="Categor" disabled selected>Category</option>
                    <option value="personal">Personal</option>
                    <option value="buisness">Buisness</option>
                    <option value="You">You </option>
                <svg class="transform -rotate-90 absolute pointer-events-none inline flex" style="right: 12px;" width="22"
                    height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22">
                     <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                       <path stroke="#000" stroke-opacity=".012" stroke-width=".5" d="M21 1v20.16H.84V1z">
                       </path>
                       <path fill="#222"
                             d="M13.854 7.224l-3.847 3.856 3.847 3.856-1.184 1.184-5.04-5.04 5.04-5.04z"></path>
                   </g>
               </svg>    
                </select>
```

The svg is inside the select.

Move it out!

```html
<span>
                <select class="font-semi bold text-sm appearance-none bg-gray-200 inline-block p-5 px-5 py-2 rounded-2xl ">
                    <option value="Categor" disabled selected>Category</option>
                    <option value="personal">Personal</option>
                    <option value="buisness">Buisness</option>
                    <option value="You">You </option>
                   
                </select>
                <svg class="transform -rotate-90 absolute pointer-events-none inline flex" style="right: 12px;" width="22"
                    height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22">
                     <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                       <path stroke="#000" stroke-opacity=".012" stroke-width=".5" d="M21 1v20.16H.84V1z">
                       </path>
                       <path fill="#222"
                             d="M13.854 7.224l-3.847 3.856 3.847 3.856-1.184 1.184-5.04-5.04 5.04-5.04z"></path>
                   </g>
               </svg>
```

For making the `<` on the right:

```css
svg {
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

It works when the select is on the top:

```css
svg {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<span>
                <select class="font-semi bold text-sm appearance-none bg-gray-200 inline-block p-5 px-5 py-2 rounded-2xl ">
                    <option value="Categor" disabled selected>Category</option>
                    <option value="personal">Personal</option>
                    <option value="buisness">Buisness</option>
                    <option value="You">You </option>
                   
                </select>
                <svg class="transform -rotate-90 absolute pointer-events-none inline flex" style="right: 12px;" width="22"
                    height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22">
                     <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                       <path stroke="#000" stroke-opacity=".012" stroke-width=".5" d="M21 1v20.16H.84V1z">
                       </path>
                       <path fill="#222"
                             d="M13.854 7.224l-3.847 3.856 3.847 3.856-1.184 1.184-5.04-5.04 5.04-5.04z"></path>
                   </g>
               </svg>
```

[image: The left facing triangle is on the extreme right of the page, with the CSS above.]

Look what happens if you have stuff above! It works:

```css
svg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div><strong>this is bold</strong> iqjr 98qc0 v0q89ure qoicqje oqircjoe iaewc r</div>
<span>
                <select class="font-semi bold text-sm appearance-none bg-gray-200 inline-block p-5 px-5 py-2 rounded-2xl ">
                    <option value="Categor" disabled selected>Category</option>
                    <option value="personal">Personal</option>
                    <option value="buisness">Buisness</option>
                    <option value="You">You </option>
                   
                </select>
                <svg class="transform -rotate-90 absolute pointer-events-none inline flex" style="right: 12px;" width="22"
                    height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22">
                     <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                       <path stroke="#000" stroke-opacity=".012" stroke-width=".5" d="M21 1v20.16H.84V1z">
                       </path>
                       <path fill="#222"
                             d="M13.854 7.224l-3.847 3.856 3.847 3.856-1.184 1.184-5.04-5.04 5.04-5.04z"></path>
                   </g>
               </svg>
```

This also works:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
#triangle {
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div><strong>this is bold</strong> ercjieo aceijrop ioejcrpa aeijrcop aeijopcr aeiojcr aeiojr aij eirojtper ieorjc</div>
<table>
<tr><td><select class="font-semi bold text-sm appearance-none bg-gray-200 inline-block p-5 px-5 py-2 rounded-2xl ">
                    <option value="Categor" disabled selected>Category</option>
                    <option value="personal">Personal</option>
                    <option value="buisness">Buisness</option>
                    <option value="You">You </option>
                   
                </select>
                
               </td>
               <td id="triangle">
               <svg class="transform -rotate-90 absolute pointer-events-none inline flex" style="right: 12px;" width="22"
                    height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22">
                     <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                       <path stroke="#000" stroke-opacity=".012" stroke-width=".5" d="M21 1v20.16H.84V1z">
                       </path>
                       <path fill="#222"
                             d="M13.854 7.224l-3.847 3.856 3.847 3.856-1.184 1.184-5.04-5.04 5.04-5.04z"></path>
                   </g>
               </svg>
               </td></tr></table>
```

**But don't use a table tag. They carry semantic meaning!**

Tables are supposed to carry *data*:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| data | more data |
| data | more data |
| data | more data |

But what if it *didn't* carry data?

| **Stack Overflow** | **Questions** |
| --- | --- |
| Home | [Why is my SVG element not appearing? (even when Inspecting my webpage)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68370059/) |
| [Users](/users) | [Why is my SVG element not appearing? (even when Inspecting my webpage)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68370059/) |

This is bad for screen readers.

So use `display:table;` instead.

```css
.faketable {
  display:table;
}
.faketable>div {
  display:table-row;
}
.faketable>div>div {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="faketable">
<div>
<div>Cell One (aruc b)</div>
<div>Cell Two (ierjc eijac)</div>
</div>
<div>
<div>Cell Three (qrc a)</div>
<div>Cell Four (caf vfjj)</div>
</div>
</div>
```

So the second method should look more like this:

```css
.faketable {
  width: 100%;
}

#triangle {
  text-align: right;
}

.faketable {
  display: table;
}

.faketable>div {
  display: table-row;
}

.faketable>div>div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div><strong>this is bold</strong> ercjieo aceijrop ioejcrpa aeijrcop aeijopcr aeiojcr aeiojr aij eirojtper ieorjc</div>
<div class="faketable">
  <div>
    <div>
      <select class="font-semi bold text-sm appearance-none bg-gray-200 inline-block p-5 px-5 py-2 rounded-2xl ">
        <option value="Categor" disabled selected>Category</option>
        <option value="personal">Personal</option>
        <option value="buisness">Buisness</option>
        <option value="You">You </option>

      </select>

    </div>
    <div id="triangle">
      <svg class="transform -rotate-90 absolute pointer-events-none inline flex" style="right: 12px;" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22">
                     <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                       <path stroke="#000" stroke-opacity=".012" stroke-width=".5" d="M21 1v20.16H.84V1z">
                       </path>
                       <path fill="#222"
                             d="M13.854 7.224l-3.847 3.856 3.847 3.856-1.184 1.184-5.04-5.04 5.04-5.04z"></path>
                   </g>
               </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you want an image inside a select tag, you could use a custom dropdown:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

function hide(element) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("options");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
  document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'none';
  element.style.backgroundColor = "#00ffff"
}
```

```css
.options:hover {
  background-color: #00dddd !important;
}

#buttons,
.options {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.options {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

#content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1em;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button style="width: 100%;" id="buttons" class="collapsible">Click Me</button> <svg class="transform -rotate-90 absolute pointer-events-none inline flex" style="right: 12px;" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22">
                     <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                       <path stroke="#000" stroke-opacity=".012" stroke-width=".5" d="M21 1v20.16H.84V1z">
                       </path>
                       <path fill="#222"
                             d="M13.854 7.224l-3.847 3.856 3.847 3.856-1.184 1.184-5.04-5.04 5.04-5.04z"></path>
                   </g>
               </svg> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="content" style="display:none;" onblur="this.style.display='none';">
      <ul style="list-style:none;">
        <li onclick="hide(this); document.getElementById('buttons').innerHTML=this.innerHTML;" class="options">option 1</li>
        <li onclick="hide(this); document.getElementById('buttons').innerHTML=this.innerHTML;" class="options">option 2</li>
        <li onclick="hide(this); document.getElementById('buttons').innerHTML=this.innerHTML;" class="options">option 3</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```